# How to create an empty JSON object in postgresql?

Tags: json, postgresql, aggregate-functions, postgresql-9.4

### Datamodel

A person is represented in the database as a meta table row with a name and with multiple attributes which are stored in the data table as key-value pair (key and value are in separate columns).
[image: Datamodel]
*Simplified data-model*

Now there is a query to retrieve all users (**name**) with all their attributes (**data**). The attributes are returned as JSON objects in a separate column. Here is an example:

```json
name      data
Florian   { "age":25 }
Markus    { "age":25, "color":"blue" }
Thomas    {}
```

The SQL command looks like this:

```sql
SELECT
  name,
  json_object_agg(d.key, d.value) AS data
FROM meta AS m
JOIN (
  SELECT d.fk_id, d.key, d.value AS value FROM data AS d
  ) AS d
ON d.fk_id = m.id
GROUP BY m.name;
```

### Problem

Now the problem I am facing is, that users like **Thomas** which do not have any attributes stored in the **key-value** table, are not shown with my select function. This is because it does only a `JOIN` and no `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

If I would use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` then I run into the problem, that `json_object_agg` try's to aggregate `NULL` values and dies with an error.

### Approaches

#### 1. Return an empty list of keys and values

So I tried to check if the **key-column** of a user is `NULL` and return an empty array so `json_object_agg` would create an empty **JSON** object.

But there is not really a function to create an empty array in SQL. The nearest thing I found was this:

```sql
select '{}'::text[];
```

In combination with `COALESCE` the query looks like this:

```sql
json_object_agg(COALESCE(d.key, '{}'::text[]), COALESCE(d.value, '{}'::text[])) AS data
```

But if I try to use this I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  COALESCE types text and text[] cannot be matched
LINE 10:     json_object_agg(COALESCE(d.key, '{}'::text[]), COALES...
                                                ^
Query failed
PostgreSQL said: COALESCE types text and text[] cannot be matched
```

So it looks like that at runtime `d.key` is a single value, not an array.

#### 2. Split up JSON creation and return an empty list

So I tried to take `json_object_agg` and replace it with `json_object` which does not **aggregate** the keys for me:

```sql
json_object(COALESCE(array_agg(d.key), '{}'::text[]), COALESCE(array_agg(d.value), '{}'::text[])) AS data
```

But there I get the error that `null value not allowed for object key`. So `COALESCE` does not check that the array is empty.

### Question

So, is there a function to check if a joined column is empty, and if yes return just a simple JSON object?

Or is there any other solution that would solve my problem?

Comment: "it looks like at runtime d.key is a single value and not an array" - I'm not sure what you mean by "at runtime". If `d.key` is a column, then you must know what type it is. From the error message, it appears to be type `text`; so an empty value would be `''` (or `text ''` or `''::text` if you want to be explicit).

Comment: Yes that's right, it is just text. But I thought it would be a list of text's because I reference there the whole column. But that was my misunderstanding of the SQL syntax. So with **at runtime** I mean when the query will be executed.

Comment: Ah, yes, I see. As a clearer example that it's referencing a value not the whole column, consider that the following works: `Select sum(some_column + 1) From some_table` - the `+1` has to act on each value separately before bundling them up into the `sum`.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Use left join and `coalesce()` with an empty json object `'{}'::json` as a default value.

```sql
select 
    name, 
    coalesce(d.data, '{}'::json) as data
from meta m
left join (
    select 
        fk_id, 
        json_object_agg(d.key, d.value) as data
    from data d
    group by fk_id
    ) d
on m.id = d.fk_id;
```

Test it in [db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/ExoWsl5L)